# Error when adding provider package to flutter web project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-provider

I tried to add the provider package to my flutter web project and got the following error:

> Because every version of provider depends on flutter any from sdk which is >forbidden, provider is forbidden.
>   So, because WebApplication depends on provider ^3.0.0, version solving >failed.
>
> Flutter users should run `flutter packages get` instead of `pub get`.
>   Process finished with exit code 69

I tried `flutter packages get` and also upgraded flutter to the newest version. 
When running `flutter packages get` the error is not shown but when i tried `webdev serve` the following error is shown:

> webdev could not run for this project.
>   Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in >"C:\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\provider-3.0.0".

also i looked ad https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21338 but didn't solve my error.

Im using  Flutter (Channel beta, v1.6.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.765], locale de-DE)

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  provider: ^3.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0
```

Comment: Because Flutter Web requires the beta channel null safety is required. There is a prerelease 5.0.0v available to date @ https://pub.dev/packages/provider/versions/5.0.0-nullsafety.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is already answered here: https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/issues/82

Use `flutter_web` branch of kevmoo's `https://github.com/kevmoo/provider` povider fork as:

```
dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any
  provider: any

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui
  provider:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/kevmoo/provider
      ref: flutter_web
```

Answer (score 0):

you can take any package and supported in flutter web by take source code packages from github and take codes inside lib file inside package and put it in your project and fix errors may happen inside files by change path import to: import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart'; and some more changes may need to do it.

it will work 100% and so easy :)

[image]