# Error when add Provider package in flutter app

Tags: flutter, provider, state-management

I want to add Provider package in my flutter app, but has error like follow image:

```
flutter pub pub add provider
```

[image]

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534998/error-when-adding-provider-package-to-flutter-web-project) don't solve it

Comment: what futter and pub version you using ?

Comment: flutter version is 2.0.4 and dart sdk version is 2.12.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it :)
The name of your project can not be equal to package name.
The name of my project is provider and that is compiler gave an error.

Answer (score 1):

In your package's ***pubspec.yaml*** add this line like below. Then run **pub get/pub upgrade**:

```
dependencies:
  provider: ^5.0.0
```

Note: Indentation must be considered. Not valid

```
dependencies:
provider: ^5.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to versioning error.

In your pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
    provider:
```

Leave the version blank, it will automatically select the best one according to
the other packages.
After this run `flutter pub get`